# Oracle DB - what software do I need to learn Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

I'm thinking of learning Oracle SQL  and PL/SQL. So what softwares do I need

- Oracle 12c DB
- SQL Developer and Data Modeler

or both.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need both, `Oracle 12c DB` is the database engine, while `SQL Developer and Data Modeler` is the client you will use to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could download Oracle developer VM to learn. It comes with lot of learning material and you don't need to do setup yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you as an individual learn best and what skills you wish to gain, you may want to look for something to add some practical context and realism  - ultimately you can do this right up to the point where you are struggling with many of the same "undocumented features" as Oracle professionals.

- If you code at all you could get a toolchain that allow you to interact with the database from your favourite language, if you don't you may want to look for an interesting application that can run on Oracle database.
- Books, hands-on-labs, whitepapers often suggest useful tools or other
  software relevant their particular topic.
- If you have an interest for operations, you may want to play with
  Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control (I believe there is a nice VM
  template with everything preconfigured on Orale Technology Network).
  if only to feel extent of the pain before looking into more widely
  used automation tools like Ansible or Salt and start looking at how
  they can do Oracle for you. Check out disruptive new technologies
  such as Docker and Vagrant, and see if you glimpse their future in an
  Oracle context. Even if you can't they have the potential to be
  fantastic learning tools.
- Check out RAC Attack and Rep Attack to quickly build complex,
  production like lab environments in virtual machines. Unless you also
  have some hardware capable of production like performance, the
  likeness is of course limited to mean architectural concepts and
  software configuration.
- The RAC Attack gyus also offer a Vagrantfile these days, that while
  increasing rather than decreasing the total time to deploy, will let 
  you deploy a RAC environment with a single command. I think most that have a good idea of everything involved find the idea a bit impressive. I know I do.
- While you are at it, get a hold of the Oracle ZFS Storage Appliance
  Simulator. It will let you play with a very nearly fully featured
  virtual edition of a ZFS-SA that you can even be upgraded with the
  same official software images you would use on the real deal. Follow
  some hands-on labs or take closer look at at least a couple of
  technologies for state of the art database and storage integration.

Looking at this short list alone, it's clear that the tools available today allow learning and testing on a level that until very recently was completely unachievable outside of the enterprise datacenter.

Good Luck!